# Error when trying to import SQL database to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

Import failed: exit status 1 ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'. Not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the dump collation is not compatible. You may want to take the dump again.

> mysqldump -u username -p --compatible=mysql4 database_name >
>   database_name.sql

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a previously imported .sql file
2. Search: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
3. Replace utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci with utf8mb4_general_ci
4. Save and retry import

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is related ANSI_QUOTES enabled on DO.

You can resolve this by going to the settings tab of your DO database, editing "Global SQL modes" and then removing ANSI_QUOTES. After that, reconnect with workbench or TablePlus, and you'll get the expected result.

See image here
[image: here is the solution]